# Breaking bundles into individual line items without custom code

Tags: bundled-product

We have a few bundled items as a part of a "mix and match" promo. They work great in that the customer can pick two different items and they are sold as a pair. There is just one problem - and that is working with our third party logistics partner for fulfillment. Looking at an invoice for a particular order with a bundle, it lists only the parent "bundle" sku. This is problematic when we send the invoice to the warehouse as that parent sku doesn't actually exist, and they have no information as to what individual child skus to fulfill. How can we make the invoices list the child skus instead of just the parent sku?

In the bundle edit page, I found this dropdown, but I can't find any documentation as to what exactly it does. Will toggling this accomplish my goal?

[image: ship bundle items]

I've found a few other stackexchange posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592719/bundle-product-add-to-cart-as-individual-line-items) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915427/magento-adding-simple-products-from-a-bundle-to-separate-lines-in-the-cart) that deal with the same issue but they are pretty old and either don't exactly solve my problem or deal with the source code.

I should also add I do not have access to the source code so manually extending the functionality is out of the question. I *may* have access to install some plugins but I will have to go through our host.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you point out is just the option for that.

- `Together` selected will only give you the possibility to send them at once.
- `Separate` selected will give you the option to create more than one shipment.

It is still possible to invoice them separately.

For your convenience I've tested it and added screens with just the product option saved between creating of two orders.

Creating a shipping with separate enabled.
[image: separate]

Creating a shipping with together enabled.
[image: together]